# How can I prevent Scala from evaluating arguments before they are passed to the macro implementation?

Tags: scala, macros

Please take a look at the following macro I built (actually, more or less copied, from [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZVYdiAudr-I) wonderful talk):

```
import scala.language.experimental.macros
import scala.reflect.macros.blackbox.Context

object SimpleAssert {
   def simpleAssert(expr: Boolean): Unit = macro simpleAssertMacro
   def simpleAssertMacro(c: Context)(expr: c.Tree): c.Tree = {
    import c.universe._
    expr match {
      case q"$a == $b" =>
        q"""
          if ($a != $b) 
            throw new AssertionError($a + " != " + $b)
        """
      case _ =>
        q"""
          Predef.assert($expr)
        """
    }
  }
}
```

If I do `simpleAssert(x == y)`, it works like a charm. However, if I do `simpleAssert(21 == 42)`, the pattern matching doesn't work as expected and `Predef.assert` is being called. That is because in the latter case, `expr` is `false` and not `21 == 42`. How can I prevent Scala from evaluating arguments before they are passed to the macro implementation?

Comment: Have you tried defining the parameter as "by-name"? take a look: https://issues.scala-lang.org/browse/SI-5778

Comment: Didn't work -- good idea, though! Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think, that's a known long-standing bug in Scala:

[[SI-6044] Constant folding happens before macro expansion](https://issues.scala-lang.org/browse/SI-6044)

I believe, this won't be fixed in the current macro implementation, as the work is now being done on the new metaprogramming framework [scala.meta](http://scalameta.org/).

Comment: Is there any workaround for this? Defining parameters as call-by-name didn't work, but there must be a way... :D

Comment: @baerenfaenger It seems that there aren't any workarounds. The current behaviour seems to be an important part of Scala metaprogramming. In many applications it is useful to interpret constant expressions as actual literals. I've just found several topics where Martin Odersky, Eugene Burnako and others were mentioning ways to implement fixes in the macro library to get the original Tree together with the literal value, but it seems they've never got to it, and later decided to switch to this new metaprograming library scala.meta. I'm not an expert on this and may be wrong though.